# Confusion about Python list slice results

Tags: python, list

I'm new to Python, the following output I'm getting from a simple list slice operation confused the jebuse out of me.

Here is the code.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4];
>>> a[1:3]
[2, 3]

>>> a[3]
4
```

shouldn't `a[1:3]` returns `[2,3,4]` instead of `[2,3]`?

Answer (score 9):

`a[1:3]` specifies a *half-closed interval*, which means it includes the values starting at the *1st* specified index up to, *but not including*, at the *2nd* index.

So in this case `a[1:3]` means the slice includes `a[1]` and `a[2]`, but *not* `a[3]`

You see the same in the use of the [range()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) function. For instance

```
 range(1, 5)
```

will generate a list from 1 to 4, but will *not* include 5.

This is pretty consistent with how things are done in many programming languages.

Comment: thanks for editing it to make to make it clearer, though i don't know what you mean by 'a half interval'

Comment: @darkphoenix half-closed interval means that the range includes only one of the values, and not the other. In math notation we'd write this as `[1, 5)` to mean 1, 2, 3, 4, whereas `[1, 5]` is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 (if I remember my math notation correctly .. it's been a while :) .. see also this: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Half-ClosedInterval.html

Comment: For details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-closed_interval#Classification_of_intervals

Answer (score 1):

Slicing returns up to (but not including) the second slice index.

Answer (score 1):

The docs for [slice](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#slice) may help.

> **slice([start], stop[, step])**
>   Return a slice object representing the
>   set of indices specified by `range(start, stop, step)`.

The slice format that most of are familiar with is just a shorthand:

```
a[start:stop:step]
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got some good answers about how it works, here's one with why:

> > > a = '0123456789'
> > >       a[2:4]
> > >       '23'
> > >       a[4:6]
> > >       '45'
> > >       a[6:8]
> > >       '67'

IOW, it makes it easy to step through a list or string or tuple n characters at a time, without wasting time on the +1 / -1 stuff needed in most languages.